# ways to express joy, or basic humor in a situation (for a story)

Tags: novel, book, humor, story

not exactly sure how to solve this, and haven't used the app before. Just started story writing. So ya, I don't know what else to say

Comment: Have you ever experienced joy yourself, or heard a joke?  If you have, how did you feel?  How did you react physically?  What did it make you think of the situation?  of the other people involved?  As you answer these questions, take notes, and you're off to a good start.

Comment: Can you give any more details? For example, what point of view or why what you're doing now isn't working? Take a look at [How can I write humor as character trait?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/43858/34330), which has a very good level of detail.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What app are you talking about? StackExchange?

Answer (score 2):

I've always used just a simple, 'he grinned' or 'smiled, or for greater effect 'chuckled' or 'laughed', during the dialog tag. I don't know your context, so I can't say which one to put there. This may seem simplistic, but it makes the effect.

Answer (score 1):

You could communicate it through verbs, like-
Laughed
Chuckled,
etc.
Or you could show the thoughts of your characters.
Or, you could also use body language.